# Booting from usb drive with QEMU

Tags: x86, qemu, bootloader, osdev

I'm playing with my hobby [operating system](https://github.com/povilasb/simple-os).
It has a simple BIOS based [bootloader](https://github.com/povilasb/simple-os/blob/master/bootloader/boot.asm) that uses [int 0x13; ah=0x42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#INT_13h_AH.3D42h:_Extended_Read_Sectors_From_Drive) to load data from usb drive.

My bootloader perfectly reads sectors if I run qemu like this:

```
$ qemu-system-i386 -usb -usbdevice disk:sos.img
```

But if I try to boot from physical device:

```
$ sudo dd if=sos.img of=/dev/sdb
$ sudo qemu-system-i386 -usb -usbdevice disk:/dev/sdb
```

bootloader fails to read the sectors.

What's the difference between image file and usb device from qemu's perspective?

Comment: Just a wild guess: maybe it's a problem that you write the image _to the drive_ (`/dev/sdb`) and not _to a partition_ (`/dev/sdb1`). This could be the cause of various problems (e.g. missing partition table).

Comment: Well, the drive is unpartitioned. And I believe BIOS reads raw sectors. Maybe it even does not understand the filesystems.

Comment: This is surely not the problem but perform any memory operation *after* segments initialization. Move `mov [boot_disk], dl ` a few lines down. Also, It's good practice to attempt a read a few times before giving up and to print the error code (which comes handy in cases like this).

Comment: In addition to Margaret's comment about `dl` your usage of `disk:` is wrong. That only applies to files, not devices. You can however do this with USB. Run command `lsusb` . Find your storage device. Make note of the ID which will be xxxx:xxxx . Now run qemu with `sudo qemu-system-i386 -usb -usbdevice host:xxxx:xxxx` where xxxx:xxxx is the ID number from `lsusb`

Comment: Thank you folks :)
@MichaelPetch that worked :) I would accept it as an answer ;)

Comment: For the sake of completeness: http://wiki.osdev.org/Problems_Booting_From_USB_Flash